# PHP / MySQL Need a Database Class

Tags: php, mysql, database, class, codeigniter

I need some help.  I am working on a project and I found myself writing a bunch of functions for grabbing information from the database:

**For Example:**

```
function getSlideByUserAndSortId($sort_order) {
global $mysqli;
global $user_id;

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT slide_id FROM user_slides WHERE user_id = ? AND sort_order = ?")) {
    $stmt->bind_param('ii', $user_id, $sort_order);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($returnSlideId);
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->fetch();

    return $returnSlideId;

    $stmt->close();
}
}

function getSlideText($var) {
global $mysqli;
global $user_id;
global $current_slide;

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT text FROM slide_data WHERE slide_id = ? AND user_id = ? LIMIT 1")) {
    $stmt->bind_param('ii', $current_slide, $user_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($text);
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->fetch();

    $text = ($stmt->num_rows < 1 ? $var : $text);

    return $text;

    $stmt->close();
}
}
```

Which is so messy.. What I need is a class like Codeigniter where I can just do:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('blogs');
$this->db->join('comments', 'comments.id = blogs.id');

$query = $this->db->get();
```

How does everyone else do it?  If you have a lot of information you need to grab and a lot of queries, what is the best way to display the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is an [Object Relational Mapper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) and there have been many created for use with PHP and MySql. Some of the best and most widely used are [Propel](http://propel.phpdb.org/trac/) and [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/)

However you cand find many other suggestions on this stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108699/good-php-orm-library)

Comment: +1. I can personally recommend doctrine, it speeds up my development a lot.